# Axios Promise is Resolving undefined

Tags: ecmascript-6, axios

My axios promise is returning undefined as the response.

Although I can see in the dev tools there is a successful response and a body.

```
app.$axios.post('auth/refresh')
  .then(({ data: { access_token } }) => {
    return Promise.resolve(access_token);
  });
```

This code results in the below error:

[image: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined]

How come it is undefined when I have the below response?

[image: API Response]

As far as I can see the request is fine, headers below too:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code you provided does not emit that error message even when axios would resolve with an empty value. Also your example response does not seem to be a standard response from axios.

Comment: Does the axios promise resolve with exactly the body? Log the value that your `then` callback is receiving.

Comment: @str how would I provide a minimal reproducible for this it requires an API and a frontend application. The example provided is the output from the network tab in Chrome Debug tools not directly from axios, I use JSON API standard wrapping successful responses in data.

Comment: @bergi I tried that the value is undefined if I log it, I've done almost everything conceivable (I've been on it for 12 hours plus)

Comment: @OliverGiess No, the value is not `undefined`, otherwise the error you were getting was about accessing the `.data` property, not about accessing the `.access_token` property. What is the value that you receive? Do `app.$axios.post('auth/refresh').then(console.log)`